# Why does my Armature deform so incorrectly?

Tags: armature, parent

I have been trying to create a rig for my model of a dragon (it is a school project). I have constraints on the eye, inverse kinematics on the legs, and a spline restriction on the tail.

I stupidly made the teeth as a separate object, sculpted the mouth to include the teeth, and then used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to make it a part of the dragon. Before using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, the teeth moved very weirdly but everything else worked. After joining the teeth everything went weird. How do I made this armature work?

[image: This is the base model]

[image: Parent the Armature]

[image: The model is ruined]

[image: The teeth are the biggest problem]

Answer (score 0):

In your armature, the lower jaw bone is too high, lower it. Also influence zone may be too big. Hence, lower jaw bone moves upper jaw and vice versa. If this doesn't work **re-sculpt, in addition, the teeth but not as a separate object.**<kbd>Ctrl+J</kbd> can mess things up as it is e.g. with texture mapping.

Comment: the location of the bones worked perfectly fine beforehand. Why does ctr+j mess things up and how can i fix it

Comment: I don't know why it does, do what is written in boldface.